# Mysql charset and form

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I have a problem with MySQL and charsets .

When I insert something into my mysql database, the special chars like "é" change into "Ã¨" and some other strange character combinations...

Searching on the web, I read about set utf8_unicode_ci tables and general configuration. I also added the following line to my webpage

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

But after all this it always returns the same error when I insert something into the database. The characters are still garbled.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add this to your code:

```
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
```

It will tell PHP to use Unicode to talk with the database engine. So if your form data encoding is unicode too, you shouldn't have any garbled characters problems anymore.

Comment: yes i use PHP ... where i have to use mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8"); ? right after DB connect?? 
however collation is set to utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: The same thing can also be accomplished with `mysql_set_charset("utf8")`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php